# Add to cart is not working in magento

Tags: javascript, magento

[image]I was using a custom theme in magento and after adding swatches it was showing drop down list for colors in the product description page, where as I wanted to add normal color swatches in the page.
I took the reference of the following link

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/how-to-use-magento-1-9-1-0-configurable-swatches-in-default-package-theme-or-a

Luckily it worked but it is showing errors when I use "Add to cart"

swatches-product.js:542 Uncaught ReferenceError: PointerManager is not defined(…)

I hav also attached the screenshot

[image]

Comment: replace $j with jQuery and check

Comment: Already done, it dint worked @AdityaSingh

Comment: @raw_hitt Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @Rathinam yes i did

Comment: There was conflict in button class simply changed the class name in cart.php

Comment: @raw_hitt Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

This is may be because of jQuery coinflict, go in settings, in cart and disable the jQuery

Comment: that was not the exact solution but it was also one of the reasons for the error